# Give Non Root user access to start mysqld service

Tags: sudo, root, service

I have a Non Root User `abc` and want to give the user `sudo` rights only to `restart`, `start` or `stop` - `mysqld service`. i.e `sudo service mysqld restart`. How can I do it so?

> I would like to do the same to usergroup too!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following lines in /etc/sudoers

```
dba01 ALL=/sbin/service mysqld start
dba01 ALL=/sbin/service mysqld stop
dba01 ALL=/sbin/service mysqld restart
```

this config will allow dba01 user to execute all three commands.

Now here is the output

```
[dba01@APP01 root]$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld restart
[sudo] password for dba01:
Shutting down mysqld:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting mysqld:                                             [  OK  ]
```

If you try to run any other service

```
[dba01@APP01 root]$ sudo /sbin/service ip6tables restart
Sorry, user dba01 is not allowed to execute '/sbin/service ip6tables restart' as root on APP01.
```

Comment: You don't need all three lines; allowing `/sbin/service mysqld` will grant permission to run it with any arguments.

Comment: no , I tested it , it does not work without full command

Comment: could you please tell my the same for user groups too....i have updated my question

Comment: use %groupName rather dba01

Answer (score 0):

granting permissions to allow the group to run `sudo service`, would give them permission to restart any service. I would simply grant them access to the init script.

You can do this by adding the following line to the sudoers file

```
%groupName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/mysql
```

Then the group members should be able to run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: please explain in detail step by step

Comment: i used `sudo visudo` to go to sudoers file....then i added a line `User_Alias      GROUPONE = abc1,abc2,abc3,...`

Comment: After that i added this line `%GROUPONE ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/mysql`